# Custom polyfit model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, polynomials, polynomial-approximations

I've got two arrays;

```
R = [r0, r1, r2, ..., r999]

Z = [z0, z1, z2, ..., z999]
```

I want to apply polyfit to the above, where the function is R(z). I need the polynomial to be x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8

In excel, the trend function does not allow for only even powers, so I've tried to write this in Matlab, but I can't figure out how customise polyfit so that it only uses even powers as described above.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Least Squares Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) from linear algebra to solve this:

```
% The Data
R = [r0, r1, r2, ..., r999]'; % Note the apostrophe
Z = [z0, z1, z2, ..., z999]';

% Create Vandermonde-ish matrix
X = [Z.^2 Z.^4 Z.^6 Z.^8];

% Solve equation system
a = X\R;

% Reshape and pad with zeros for the odd and 0th powers
p = [zeros(size(a)) a]';
pval = flip([0; p(:)]);
```